# discord.py using Lists in message.content?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    wordfilter = ['badword', 'anotherone', 'and the last one']
    if wordfilter in message.content:
        await message.delete()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:path/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:path/combot.py", line 34, in on_message
    if wordfilter in message.content:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

I want a wordfilter, with tons of words in it, so id like to have a list where i can add all my words (later even with command from Discord).
But i really do not know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check if a list is in a string, you did it wrong. What you're trying to do is `if message.content in wordfilter` but this also won't work. You need to get every word in the message then check if one of them is in the `wordfilter` and also you need to create the `wordfilter` list out of the event so it won't create a new list for everytime and it makes your code more optimized. So you can simply do it in one line:

```py
wordfilter = ['badword', 'anotherone', 'and the last one']
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    [await message.delete() for word in message.content.split(' ') if word in wordfilter]
```

So, it will split your message content from the spaces and check if one of the words are in wordfilter. If it is, it will delete the message.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Just wanna let you know that i dont have enough reputation do vote your answer up.
It really helped me.